# HAML variable Tag ie. %foo or %#{foo} possible?

Tags: haml, middleman

Is it possible in HAML to create variable TAGs as the subject asks?

Want to do

```
- tag = "h1"


%tag
```

Cheers

Final Version I used was

```
-# Type Default
- if ! defined? locals[ :type ]
    - type = "h1"
- else
    - type = locals[ :type ]

-# Heading
- haml_tag type do

    -# Main Text
    = locals[:text]

    -# Add the secondary text if required
    -if defined? locals[ :small ]
        %small= locals[ :small ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible.

Try this.

```
- tag = 'h1'
- haml_tag tag, "I'm h1."
```

Comment: awesome let me try that - cool URL provided for completeness - http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html